# Python - Comparing multiple columns

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I am trying to deactivate certain products from inventory if all their sizes have zero stock, from a csv using pandas. Psuedo - group all the products by "desc" and if all "instock" equals zero then return true to "inactive"

I have tried using groupby function with pandas, but can't get my head around how it works.

Here is the csv, and me trying to explain what I mean ...

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can check with `groupby` `transform`

```
df['instack']=df['instack'].eq(0).groupby(df['desc']).transform('all')
```

Comment: What can I say, thankyou very much! Will have to lookup how that transform works, looks very handy.

-e- Is there a way to put the transform output into the "inactive" column?

Comment: @user3170725 you can just assign it back like what i did

Answer (score 1):

```
df.loc[df.groupby('desc')['instock'].transform(sum).eq(0), 'inactive'] = 'T'
```

The groupby/transform returns a Boolean mask where the sum of the instock series per group equals zero.  This get's wrapped in a dataframe loc statement to choose only those rows where the mask is True, and sets the inactive column to 'T'.